# Screen record at a higher resolution (ex: 4K) than my physical monitor (only 1080p)

Tags: video, nvidia, saas, obs

I frequently need to record the screen and edit it into a demo video.

The best software I've found so far is OBSproject.com, free, open-source, very flexible streaming and screen-recording software.

I would kill to be able to **record at a higher resolution (ex: 4K) than my physical monitor (only 1080p)** and then zoom in losslessly when editing.

Any wizards out there aware of a way to do this? Would be a giant help when creating these software demo videos! If the answer is another capture software or some FFMPEG magic, I'm down.

p.s. I have run across the **Nvidia setting "DSR Factors"** but, when testing this out, looks like it is a *LOSSY UPSCALE,* not really 4k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out Nvidia DSR Factors DOES allow true 4k recording from a 1080p monitor.

I had to make sure DSR was turned to 4x, then in Windows "Change Display Settings", set the resolution to 3140x2160, then restart the computer, finally in OBS change the Video input/output resolution to 3140x2160.

My setup:

- Windows 10
- OBS
- Nvidia GTX970
- Adobe Creative Cloud for editing